# mouseReleaseEvent triggers at application start, not on click in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Inside of a Python 3.5 app written using PyQt5 I have mouseReleaseEvents like so

```
self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = self.setScene("1")
```

When they have variables to pass, they all trigger when the application starts, and they don't trigger when actually clicked.

However, if I remove the variable, they work when pressed, and they don't trigger at application start:

```
self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = self.setScene
```

But I have to get a variable over to this function

```
def setScene(self, scene):
    print(scene)
```

Any suggestions as to why the variable causes this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in every GUI when you bind function to event you have to use function name - it means without `()` and arguments.

You can have two method

- "boring": create function without arguments and assign to event

  ```
  def new_fun(self):
      self.setScene("1")

  self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = self.new_fun
  ```
- "popular": use `lambda` to create anonymouse function

  ```
  self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda:self.setScene("1")
  ```

---

I don't know but `mouseReleaseEvent` may run function with `event` object which has information about event so you have to grab it

```
self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda event:self.setScene("1")
```

---

If you have to use `lambda` in `for x` loop and use `x` in `lambda` function then you need

```
for x in some_list:
   self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda event, arg=x :self.setScene(arg)
```

because `lambda` is `"lazy"` and it doesn't copy value from `x` to function when you define `lambda` but it gets value from `x` when you release mouse - but at that momen `x` has last value from `some_list`.

Comment: self.scene1.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda event:self.setScene("1") that was EXACTLY what was needed. Thank you so so much!